# Conversion of delimited .Txt file into Excel file

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, javascript, ms-dos, vbscript

I have a delimited .Txt file containing several fields (separated by spaces) and I want to know how can I copy the entire thing into the MS Excel using any script (JS/VB/DOS Command) which can be useful in this matter.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Excel can open standard .csv files, so renaming to .csv may help (Excel also allows the delimiter to be specified, so a space character is an acceptable delimiter). This could be achieved with a VB script.

If you do not require full automation and can use the UI, then you can use (Using Excel 2010 here)

Data > From Text

From there you specify how excel should import your text data. Once it's in you can save in any (Excel) format you like.

[image]

Comment: That wizard will allow a space to be the delimiter, no modification is required

Comment: Edited answer as per above comment.